# Edit Method WPF | Dynamic Parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters

**Situation**

I'm trying to make an edit member method for my WPF application.

Basically, I have a list of members in my main class, I iterate through that list of members and find the member with the matching Username parameter, that works.

Then, once that username is found within the system (which it will be since the member needs to login with a valid one) I want to set the member."Whatever" paramater to whatever parameter the user chose to edit on the gui, with the new content the user has entered for that parameter.

```
public void editMember(string Username, string parameter, string newEntry)
        {



            foreach (BaseMember bm in members)
            {

                if (Username == bm.username)
                {
                    bm.[parameter] = newEntry;
                }
            }
```

**Problem**

I don't want to do:

"member.club" and "member.firstname", or "member.street", since there are far too many parameters that can be edited by the user, and it's long winded "bad" code.

how can I do this in ONE line of code? since `bm.[parameter] = newEntry;` won't work?

**More info**

This method works if I use a static parameter, for instance, `bm.memclub = newEntry;` but I want the parameter to be dynamic.

Comment: Why you don't add a switch an test your parameter name

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm relatively new to OOP.

Comment: Ok i bet Reflection is what you need just try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx):

```
      foreach (BaseMember bm in members)
        {

            if (Username == bm.username)
            {  
                Type type = bm.GetType();

                PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(parameter);

                prop.SetValue (bm, newValue, null);
            }
        }
```

Reflection provides objects (of type Type) that describe your current object.You can use reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties.

Comment: I think this worked! awesome dude, this helped tons!

Comment: do you know how the reflection class works? how does it do this when my initial code couldn't?

Comment: hey bro can you give me an upvote, I give you some information about reflection